# invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, subscript

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    float n;
    float fact(float m)
    {
    float prod=1;
    while(m>1)
     { 
      prod*=m;
      m--;
     }
    return prod;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////
    float min(float b[],float n)
    { float small=999999999999;
    for(float f=0;f<n;f++)
        if(b[f]<small)
            small=b[f];
    return small;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////
    float max(float a[],float n)
    { float small=-999999999999;
       for(float i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i]>small)
            small=a[i];
      return small;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////
    float sum(float a[],float n)
    {float sum=0;
    for(float i=0;i<n;++i)
    sum+=a[i];
    return sum;
    }

    int main() {
    float t,q2,count=0;

        scanf("%d",t);
    float *n=new float[t];
    float *m=new float[t];
    float *q=new float[t];
    float *k=new float[t];
    for(float p=0;p<t;++p)
    {cin>>n[i]>>m[i]>>q[i]>>k[i];}
    for(float p=0;p<t;++p)
    {   
    float *a=new float[n[p]];

    for(float i=0;i<n[p];++i)
     a[i]=i+1;

    for(float i=n[p];i<=m[p];++i)
    {a[n[p]-1]=n[p];

    for(float i=0;i<k[p];++i)
    {
    for(float i=0;i<n[p];++i)
    a[i]=min(a,n[p])+sum(a,n[p])-a[i];//important
    }

    q2=max(a,n[p])-min(a,n[p]);
    if(q2==q[p])
    {count++;
    }
    }
    cout<<count*fact(n,n[p]);

    }   return 0;
    }
```

Can you please tell me my mistakes?
Following errors noted!
I think if solved any one , it will help throughout

```
        prog.cpp:16: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp:24: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp: In function 'float min(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:18: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:19: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float max(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:26: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:27: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float sum(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:34: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
        prog.cpp:42: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:43: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:44: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:45: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:47: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
        prog.cpp:50: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:52: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:55: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:55: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:58: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:60: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:64: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:64: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:65: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:69: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript

        Compilation error    time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
        prog.cpp:16: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp:24: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp: In function 'float min(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:18: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:19: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float max(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:26: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:27: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float sum(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:34: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
        prog.cpp:42: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:43: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:44: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:45: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:47: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
        prog.cpp:50: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:52: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:55: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:55: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:58: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:60: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:64: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:64: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:65: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:69: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript

        Compilation error    time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
        prog.cpp:16: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp:24: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp: In function 'float min(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:18: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:19: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float max(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:26: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:27: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float sum(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:34: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
        prog.cpp:42: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:43: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:44: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:45: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:47: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
        prog.cpp:50: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:52: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:55: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:55: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:58: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:60: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:61: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:64: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:64: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:65: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:69: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript

        Compilation error    time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
        prog.cpp:15: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp:22: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp: In function 'float min(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:17: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:18: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float max(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:24: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:25: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float sum(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:32: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
        prog.cpp:40: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:41: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:42: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:43: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:45: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
        prog.cpp:48: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:50: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:51: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:54: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:54: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:58: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:62: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:62: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:63: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:67: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript

        Compilation error    time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
        prog.cpp:15: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp:22: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
        prog.cpp: In function 'float min(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:17: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:18: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float max(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:24: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:25: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'float sum(float*, float)':
        prog.cpp:32: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
        prog.cpp:40: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:41: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:42: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:43: error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
        prog.cpp:45: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
        prog.cpp:48: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:50: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:51: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:53: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:54: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:54: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:56: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:58: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:59: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:62: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:62: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
        prog.cpp:63: error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float*' to binary 'operator=='
        prog.cpp:67: error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You cannot use a `float` in an array subscript (the part within the square brackets). Try using an `int` instead.
2. `scanf` takes a pointer as its second (and subsequent) arguments. Replace `scanf("%d", t)` with `scanf("%d",&t)`. Better still, use `cin >> t`, since you're using C++.